# Which data types can be toString?

Tags: javascript

"The undefined is not an object, so there is no toString."How do you understand this sentence?Is it that only Object can toString and none of the other six data types can toString?Which data types can be toString?

Comment: This will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: Based on what you just said, objects can have toString invoked on them.

Comment: What are the *"other six data types"* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let y = 1
console.log(y.toString()) // 1 

y = [1,"1a"]
console.log(y.toString()) // 1,1a

y = {data:1}
console.log(y.toString()) // [object Object]
```